# Group by with JPA and PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, group-by

I'm trying to use the group by in a JPA query. Let's say I have a class `Teacher` and a class `Student`. A `Teacher` can have more `Student`s and a `Student` can have only one `Teacher` (one to many).

The following JPA query:

```
Query q = this.em.createQuery(  "SELECT teacher, COUNT(student)" +
                                " FROM StudentJpa student" +
                                " JOIN student.teacher teacher" +
                                " GROUP BY teacher" +
                                " ORDER BY COUNT(student) DESC");
```

Generates the following SQL query:

```
select
        teacherjpa1_.teacher_id as col_0_0_,
        count(studentjpa0_.id) as col_1_0_,
        teacherjpa1_.teacher_id as teacher1_0_,
        teacherjpa1_.name as name0_ 
    from
        student studentjpa0_ 
    inner join
        teacher teacherjpa1_ 
            on studentjpa0_.teacher_id=teacherjpa1_.teacher_id 
    group by
        teacherjpa1_.teacher_id 
    order by
        count(studentjpa0_.id) DESC
```

On PostgreSQL 9.0 I get the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "teacherjpa1_.name"
>   must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The same error doesn't appear in PostgreSQL 9.1.

Can anyone explain me why? It seems like JPA is generating the group by in a wrong way: it should include all the `Teacher` attributes, not only the id.

This is my JPA/Hibernate/DB configuration, if necessary:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="showSql" value="${db.showSql}" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${db.generateDdl}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

    <!-- Instructs the container to look for beans with @Transactional and decorate them -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <!-- FactoryBean that creates the EntityManagerFactory  -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- A transaction manager for working with JPA EntityManagerFactories -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thanks!

**Update** - A solution is to specify `GROUP BY teacher.id, teacher.name` instead of `GROUP BY teacher`, but that's not really convenient. Is there a better solution?

Comment: This is the simplest solution in PostgreSQL 9.0.  You could also use a CTE to deal with the GROUP BY and reference the CTE in a SELECT which brought in the other columns, but that's not simpler.  Maybe you could as Heroku to offer the latest production release, mentioning why you want it?

Comment: A CTE is a solution but still it's not ideal. I know you can upgrade to 9.1 on Heroku when using a dedicated database. At the moment I'm using a shared one so I guess it could be a problem for them to upgrade to 9.1... I'll contact them anyway! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That query became valid in PostgreSQL release 9.1.  It appears that you are using PostgreSQL version 9.1 locally, and Heroku is using something earlier.

See the 9.1 release notes:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/release-9-1.html

On that page, under the Queries section, it says:

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the GROUP BY clause (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> The SQL standard allows this behavior, and because of the primary key,
>   the result is unambiguous.

To get this to work under earlier versions of PostgreSQL add *all* expressions from the select list which don't use an aggregate function to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly explains why it's not working on Heroku. In fact Heroku is still using version 9.0.

Still, why is JPA generating the group by without specifying all the `Teacher` attributes but just the id? Or how can I change the code in order to make it work on PostgreSQL 9.0? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer to explain that you can fix this by adding all non-aggregate expressions to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you, @kgrittn. Obviously this solution is not ideal but if it's the only one I'll mark this answer as accepted! Let's wait for another solution, if any... Thanks

Comment: That workaround saved my life. We are using PostgreSQL 9.0.3 so I had that problem.